MS Entra Gallery OIDC app installation issue
I have a MS Entra Gallery app ModelGen for Visio that provides integrate OIDC SSO support for a separate Visio Addin. In summary it allows the Visio AddIn to perform silent SSO and get an OAuth token to call various MS services e.g. Graph API, SharePoint ...etc.
There seems to have been a change with Entra ID whereby when trying to load the Enterprise app in a new MS Azure tenant there is a button "Sign up for ModelGen for Visio (MG4V)" per below:

Clicking the link just takes the user to the static product page. It is unclear how to install the Enterprise App. Any thoughts would be gratefully received.
Thanks
Andrew

MS Entra Approval process occurs the first time the application attempts OIDC SSO.

